# Working / To work at Google taught me how to work efficiently. - which one?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

**Scenerio:**

I used to work at Google. When I was an employee at Google, I learned how to work efficiently. Now I am not a Google employee.

**Example 1**

> **Working at Google** taught me how to work efficiently.

**Example 2**

> **To work at Google** taught me how to work efficiently.

**Question:**

One is gerund and the other is an infinitive phrase.
I think Example 1 expresses the meaning. However, I wonder whether Example 2 also expresses the same meaning.

Are both of them acceptable?

Comment: The first one might be more preferrable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 1 is correct. Example 2 is not.

Infinitive phrases, when used as nouns, refer to *the concept* of something, not the actual thing itself.

While not currently working at Google:

> **To work at Google/working at Google** is my dream job.
> I would love **to work at Google/working at Google**. *(both correct, but with slightly different meanings)*

In both cases, it could be replaced with a gerund phrase, but if you're talking about something real, like you're actually working there now, you'd have to use a gerund phrase, not the infinitive phrase:

While working at Google:

> **Working at Google** is my dream job.
> I love **working at Google**.